# How to create a zip file in the same format as the Finder's "Compress" menu item?

Tags: macos, shell, automation, zip

On Mac OS X, you can create a zip archive from the Finder by selecting some files and selecting "Compress" from the contextual menu or the File menu.  Unfortunately, the resulting file is not identical to the archive created by the `zip` command (with the default options).

This distinction matters to at least one service operated by Apple, which fails to accept archives created with the `zip` command.  Having to create archives manually is preventing me from fully automating my release build process.

How can I create a zip archive in the correct format within a shell script?

EDIT: Since writing this question long ago, I've figured out that the key difference between `ditto` and `zip` is how they handle symbolic links: because the code signature inside an app bundle contains a symlink, it needs to be preserved as a link and not stored as a regular file. `ditto` does this by default, but `zip` does not (option `-y` is required).

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Try this - create an archive using finder with a single file in it, doesn't matter what it is. Now add a file to it using command line zip. This should only modify the zip master directory, and leave whatever apple magic alone - might be enough to get pass the detectors :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the ditto command-line tool as follows:

```
ditto -ck --rsrc --sequesterRsrc folder file.zip
```

See the [ditto man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) for more.

Comment: With this, I still can't produce a .zip which has the same signature as Finder's compress function. However, I didn't know about ditto :D

Comment: Likewise, but it looks much closer than the output of 'zip'. Differences could be down to timestamps or similar.

Comment: Remember to add in --keepParent. If you read the man page (man ditto):

The command:
           ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
     will create a PKZip archive similarly to the Finder's Compress functionality.

Comment: link is dead...

Comment: @NooberMan, In the terminal, type `man ditto`.

Answer (score 20):

I have a ruby script that makes iPhone App Store builds for me, but the zips it was generating wouldn't get accepted by iTunes Connect. They were accepted if I used Finder's "Compress" function.

millenomi's answer came close for me, but this command is what ended up working. iTunes Connect accepted my build, and the app got approved and can be downloaded no problem, so it's tested.

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent AppName.app AppName.zip
```

Answer (score 11):

man ditto states:

> ```
>  The command:
>        ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
>  will create a PKZip archive similarly to the Finder's Compress functionality.
> ```

notice --keepParent

Answer (score 1):

The clue's in the tag 'automation'.

Create an action in Automator.app that uses the 'Create Archive' action, invoke it from the command-line (see 'automator').

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea there was an automator shell command!  But won't that make the little robot bounce up and down in my Dock every time I make a build?

Comment: So long as the action doesn't prompt for input, it should run unattended and with no bouncing robot of any kind.

Comment: Automator, including the command line tool, requires access to the window manager, and therefore can only be launched as part of a console session, not unattended.

Comment: Worked ok in a shell script for me; what sort of problem would you expect?