# How to create a zip from command line that preserves macOS metadata but also passes validation tests when > 4GB?

Tags: macos, zip, tar, archive, xattr

I am looking for a method of creating zip archives of files and folders on macOS that meets the following requirements:

1. Creates zips from command line (not GUI such as Finder or Archive Utility)
2. Properly preserves macOS metadata (resource forks, xattrs, acls, etc.), to the same degree as Apple's built-in Archive Utility, and ideally in the same way (sequestered to `__MACOSX` subdirectory)
3. Results in a valid compressed .zip file that will pass an `unzip -t` test without errors, even when larger than 4GB.

Bonus points if it can be done with built-in tools, but I'm open to third-party solutions as well.

Many [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107938/21436468) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741492/21436468) suggest that the solution should be a `ditto` command like the following, which is supposedly what Archive Utility itself uses under the hood:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

This may have been true at some point, but I suspect that it is no longer what Archive Utility is using (as of macOS 13 Ventura), because, for example:

- Large (> 4GB) zips created with `ditto` fail `unzip -t` tests (`extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile` / `bad zipfile offset (local header sig)`), while zips created with Archive Utility or Finder (right-click > Compress) do not have this problem.
- `zipdetails` reveals many other internal differences between zips created with `ditto` vs. Archive Utility. (For example, `ditto` zips report a `Created Zip Spec` of `15 '2.1'`, while Archive Utility zips report `14 '2.0'`.)

After some experimentation, it seems that Archive Utility zips share much more internal similarity with zips created by `tar`, such as:

```
tar --mac-metadata --format zip -cvf archive.zip -C src_parent_directory src_file_or_folder_name
```

Perhaps not coincidentally, `tar` is also [Apple's official recommendation for creating compressed file archives from terminal](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/compress-and-uncompress-file-archives-apdc52250ee-4659-4751-9a3a-8b7988150530/mac) (but only for tar archives, not zip).

Problem is: the zips created by `tar` do not seem to properly preserve mac metadata, unlike zips created by `ditto` and even unlike tars created by `tar`. For example, the following command DOES preserve xattrs, unlike the above command:

```
tar --mac-metadata -cvzf archive.tar -C src_parent_directory src_file_or_folder_name
```

But for some reason it does not behave the same way when creating a zip, even though there's nothing in the man page that would suggest this is not supported. (I've also tried various combinations of `--mac-metadata`, `--xattrs`, and `--acls`, none of which seem to make any difference.)

It seems like it must be possible somehow, since Archive Utility is able to do it. Anyone have suggestions? This longtime-lurker-firsttime-poster would be very grateful. Thanks!

[EDIT: it's been over a month and no one has answered yet... in case this makes it easier: I would also accept a solution that preserves resource forks and xattrs but NOT acls.]

## To summarize:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

Meets requirements 1 and 2, but not 3.

```
tar --mac-metadata --format zip -cvf archive.zip -C src_parent_directory src_file_or_folder_name
```

Meets requirements 1 and 3, but not 2.

```
zip -r archive.zip src_directory
```

Meets requirements 1 and 3, but not 2.

```
tar --mac-metadata -cvzf archive.tar -C src_parent_directory src_file_or_folder_name
```

Meets requirement 2, but not 1 or 3 (because result is not a zip)

`Archive Utility` and `Finder right-click > Compress...`

Meets requirements 2 and 3, but not 1.

Comment: Wow. Just tried it and `ditto` is seriously messed up on archives > 4 GB. One thing you might try is to write an AppleScript that does what you want using Archive Utility, and then calling that from the command line using `osascript`.

Comment: Or `osascript` an AppleScript that does the Finder action. Either way.