# MAC OS X alias folder/file do not persist on Windows

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, alias

I have one Folder and I have created an Alias (Short-cut) on my MAC OS Desktop. Now, when I copy that Alias from MAC OS to Windows, then it shows me a type of file as "File".

Now if I again copy that Alias from Windows to Mac OS, then that alias is now **Unix Executable** file and **Not** an Alias.

I have tried zipping that Alias, and still having the same issue. Is it possible to persist MAC Alias on Windows and when i copy that Alias back to Mac then it remains Alias.

Comment: I'm just curious, what is the use case for this?

Comment: Actually, I have my iOS framework, which consists of Alias within it.. so this creates the issue...

Comment: Why would you expect this to work?  Windows does not do symbolic links in a way compatible with Unix (which is what Mac OS is under the covers).

Comment: @JimGarrison: But I would expect that if I copy symbolic links on Windows and back to Mac OS, it would remain as it is. But this is not the behavior

Comment: Can you be specific about how are you copying the file from Mac OS to Windows, and vice versa?

Comment: There are a number of problems. Firstly symlinks and alias are different things (although Finder refers to both as Alias). Secondly an Alias has lots of data stored in its ResourceFork, which certainly isn't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac filesystems can attach a several kinds of metadata to files that are not supported by other filesystems, such as those Windows uses. Depending on exactly how the file is moved between systems, this metadata may or may not be preserved; if it gets lost, the file may become unusable.

In the case of alias files, there are two relevant pieces of metadata: the type code (which identifies the file as an alias), and the resource fork (which in the case of alias files, stores the info about where to find the original item). Alias files created by older versions of OS X actually had no regular contents (the "data fork") at all -- if their metadata got lost, you were left with an empty file of unknown type. More recent versions store the original item info in both the resource and data forks, so if the resource fork gets lost it's still usable; but if the type code is lost, the OS has no idea it's an alias, it just sees some unidentifiable data (which it mistakes for a unix executable).

In some cases, if you use the right OS X tools to copy/move files to foreign filesystems (that don't support type codes, resource forks, etc), the OS X tool will encode & store the metadata in some alternate form:

- If you use the Finder to copy a file to a FAT32 flash drive, it'll store the metadata as a separate file with a "._" prefix on the name, using [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appledouble) format. If you look at this on Windows, you'll see e.g. "alias file" and "._alias file". As long as the two files are kept together, when they get back to a Mac, it'll logically reassemble them into a single file with all its metadata.
- If you use the Finder to create a zip archive, it'll do a very similar trick where it stores the metadata as "._" files inside the zip archive (in a __MACOSX subfolder); and if you expand the archive with the Finder (actually Archive Utility), it'll reassemble the files.

  But OS X's command-line zip tools *do not* support this AppleDouble/".*" trick. If you use `zip` to create an archive, it will simply leave off the Mac-only metadata, and if you use `unzip` on an archive that contains ".*" files, it will not reassemble them. If you need to create zip archives at the command line, [`ditto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107903/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-the-same-format-as-the-finders-compress-menu-item) is actually the way to go.
- If you use the Finder to copy the files to a Windows server that uses the NTFS filesystem, it'll hide the metadata in an [alternate data stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system)#Microsoft) (a Windows-only form of advanced metadata) attached to the file, and if you use the Finder to copy it back it'll be reassembled properly. But if you use something else, or move/copy the file in a way that doesn't preserve the alternate data stream, it'll get lost.