# Code signed Mac app broken after downloading

Tags: macos, code-signing

I'm attempting to sign a Mac application using the command line, I have a script which worked well in Mountain Lion but no longer appears to work in Mavericks.

All appears to work well and running the following after signing produces the expected output:

```
> spctl -a -vvvv Name.app
Name.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: Name, Inc (HA44SZ69G3)
```

I then zip the .app, upload to Amazon S3, download and unzip and run the same command - the output is:

```
spctl -a -vvvv Name.app
Name.app: rejected
source=no usable signature
```

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me it was because it was never codesigned correctly more info here. https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/issues/905

Answer (score 11):

Are you creating and/or expanding the zip archive using OS X's command line tools? They do not properly preserve and restore OS X's complex filesystem metadata, so the restored app will not be the same as the one you signed. If you need to create a metadata-preserving zip archive at the command line, use:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

(see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107903/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-the-same-format-as-the-finders-compress-menu-item)). To expand it and reattach the metadata, use:

```
ditto -x -k archive.zip dst_directory
```

Comment: That's absolutely ludicrous; so the file is essentially not the original? Would it also fail an md5 checksum, and does this only occur with .zipped files? Thanks for sharing this info — interesting indeed.

Comment: @l'L'l md5 checksum of the individual files would match, since it depends only on the file's contents, not its metadata. However, if you created a zip in the Finder or with `ditto`, then expanded it with `unzip`, you would find there are additional files in the archive -- [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appledouble) files that are used to hold the nonstandard metadata that the zip format doesn't store natively. The Finder and `ditto` both understand AppleDouble, and will reattach the metadata to the normal files; `unzip` doesn't and will expand the AppleDouble as separate files.

Comment: I understand that, although zipping and unzipping a codesigned app should not affect the contents of what is located within the .app itself essentially invalidating the codesignature would it?

Comment: @l'L'l The 'contents' of an .app is rather complex. An OS X app is really a folder, and the folder *and* each of the subfolders and files in it can have complex metadata attached to them. The zip format only supports basic metadata, so unless some workaround (like AppleDouble encoding) is used, the zip format is incapable of fully preserving a .app (or any other OS X file or folder).

Comment: Oh yes, I'm quite familiar with the structure of application bundles; just a bit surprised about the metadata aspect. In addition to your answer I presume that creating an archive such as a `.dmg` or `.iso` in read only format would be an alternative method of preserving the metadata, although correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the unzipping as this is done by an existing deployed application. Does anyone know if this functionality changed between OSX versions?

Comment: @Tom I don't think it's changed; is it possible the zipping was done differently (e.g. with CLI in the old version, Finder in the new)? Also, can you run a comparison between the original and the zip->upload->download->unzipped version (e.g. `diff -r /path/to/original.app /path/to/downloaded.app`) and see if that shows any changes?

Comment: @l'L'l It depends on how the .dmg/.iso is created -- if it's a .dmg containing a volume in Mac OS Extended format, it'll store the metadata natively. Other formats... it depends.

Comment: @GordonDavisson this answer does work, so I think it's the one to accept but not for my needs as the unzipping is done by deployed app unfortunately.

Comment: You might still be able to fix it by figuring out how the deployed app does the unzip, and creating the archive in the matching mode. Try running the `diff`, and see what it reports.

Comment: diff reports that all of the internal binaries differ :/

Comment: In that case, something else is going on -- you'll probably have to compare at various points in the process to see where things are getting modified. Compare uploaded vs. downloaded zip files, try zipping & immediately expanding, etc, and see if you can figure out which step is modifying things.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, anyway my solution was to use `tar` instead of `zip`, like this:

`tar -czf ../my-app.tar.gz my-app.app`

Signature and notarization are preserved after compressing and uncompressing the file.

Comment: Not when the file is a bashscript :( did you ever had a problem of bash script losing codesign during tar operation?