# differences between 7-zip and "send to compressed (zipped) folder"

Tags: zip, compression

BROAD QUESTION: do all .zip archives have the same compression ratio? what is the compression ratio for the windows feature when you "send to compressed (zipped) folder"  ???   Basically, I just need to know all the specifics/properties/etc of the feature "send to compressed(zipped) folder".

SPECIFIC QUESTION: For zipping files I have been using right-click>send-to-compressed-folder. I have started writing batches to streamline some work, however, windows does not have a native command-line utility for  compression. My solution was to download the command-line version of 7-zip. what I need to know is this: when I use 7-zip in the command-line to zip up a set of files, will it be compressing the files at the same ratio as "right-click>>send-to-compressed-folder". It would help if I knew the name of that tool so that I didn't always have to type out the process . I'm sure I would get better google results too lol.  any clues to help me on my search would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I found a similar thread but deals with Mac OS X  rather than windows.  He is basically asking the same question but worded a bit differently so it might help you to understand my problem. here is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107903/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-the-same-format-as-the-finders-compress-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

ZIP format supports many algorithms with different compression ratios. Also the tools themselves can use proprietary algorithms (7Zip has its own algorithm, which is more efficient than the one used in regular ZIPs). So you need to check the effectiveness yourself on your files.

Comment: well I don't even really know where to begin with your suggestion. I just need to know how to make my "command-line compression tool" the same as my "right-click send to compressed (zipped) folder tool". you see, I send these files to somebody else and I want to make sure that, even though my process has changed, they will receive the same product.

Comment: @giovanniBUBONIC Regular ZIP tool (PKWare Zip, WinZip,) will produce ZIP-compatible archives. 7Zip needs an option to be specified in order to create ZIP archives.